# jQuery-File-Upload Basic Plugin: rails can't find the necessary js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the basic version of tor's [jquery-fileupload-rails gem](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) with my rails app, and am running into a problem with loading the required javascript.

I cloned the [jQuery File Upload Demo](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and got it working no problems. However, the default index uses the advanced uploader, and I just want the basic uploader for my app.

I thought I could get that to work in the demo app by simply replacing the code in the index.html.erb file with with the html code in the [basic setup guide](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin).

However the basic code requires some js that rails can't seem to find:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The errors I'm getting are the following:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js 404 (Not Found) localhost/:41
GET http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.fileupload.js 404 (Not Found) localhost/:42
GET http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I have added `//= require jquery-fileupload` as directed to the application.js file. I'm not sure how to get rails to find these files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: follow the instructions in the README - https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails Don't include those scripts manually in your HTML.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The README points to another page that includes the scripts manually so I got confused.